# Address of the next 32 bit register

Tags: 32-bit

There are two 32 bit registers. If for some reason the 1st register has the address 0x84000000, then what will be the HEX address of the 2nd 32 bit register (consider the two register to be one after the other)?

Comment: This doesn't even make sense. Registers don't have addresses (although they are referenced by "names" like "%eax" or something similar that might be considered an "address"). A register might contain an address, though, but that has absolutely no implications about what a different register would contain...

Comment: The correct term you're looking for is "memory" or "RAM" rather than register. The are few enough registers on a CPU that they can be individually named. Modern RAM can have billions of bytes of memory which need to be addressed numerically.

Comment: Please consider this from an hardware designer's point of view. It can also be called a 32bit memory or RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working in an embedded environment with memory mapped I/O. If `0x84000000` is the address of the first register, the following register most likely has address `0x84000004`.

**Example on a Freescale i.MX35 processor.**

Registers are identified with an offset with respect to a base address. For example, the address space of the General Purpose Timer is mapped at base address `0x53F90000`.
From the datasheet you can see the register mapping:

- GPT Control Register: `0x53F90000 + 0x0000`
- GPT Prescale Register: `0x53F90000 + 0x0004`
- GPT Status Register: `0x53F90000 + 0x0008`

and so on and so forth. You can see that consecutive 32 bit registers are mapped at 4 bytes increments.

Note that this could be specific to the processor and the architecture. I would recommend checking the datasheet of the hardware you are working on.

Comment: correct! This is what I wanted to confirm...thanks! :)